# Issue with aggregate columns when non-aggregates are not present

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm having an issue with Amazon Redshift aggregate errors when I run the following query:

```
select case when frequency between (avg(frequency) + stddev(frequency)) and (avg(frequency) - stddev(frequency)) then  round(avg(frequency) - stddev(frequency))||'-'||round(avg(frequency) + stddev(frequency))
       when frequency between (avg(frequency) + 2*stddev(frequency)) and (avg(frequency) - 2*stddev(frequency)) then  round(avg(frequency) - 2*stddev(frequency))||'-'||round(avg(frequency) + 2*stddev(frequency))
       when frequency between (avg(frequency) + 3*stddev(frequency)) and (avg(frequency) - 3*stddev(frequency)) then  round(avg(frequency) - 3*stddev(frequency))||'-'||round(avg(frequency) + 3*stddev(frequency))
          else null
           end as deviation 
from schema.table
```

;

The error tells me that I need to include frequency in a group by clause. If I do so, then I recieve "aggregates not allowed in group by". Does Anyone know why this is happening? My initial guess was that it might be a problem with data types, but messing with this did not help.

Thanks!

Comment: General GROUP BY rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." In this case you have aggregate functions (`avg`), and therefore need a GROUP BY.

Comment: You're using `frequency` column, it's average value `avg(frequency)` and standard deviation value `stddev(frequency)` all in same query? I'd suggest to split this into 2 queries (or self join) with aggregate on 1 table only and then do the select case. there might be better solution too, but my suggestion would be write the query in step by step approach and then resulting it into what you want as output instead of including everything into 1 big query which does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These queries can be confusing, you can get the aggregates separately in a sub-query, then use them on every row via a cross-join, or you can use analytic functions, which allow you to get an aggregate value without a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT case when frequency between (avg_Freq + dev_Freq) and (avg_Freq - dev_Freq) then  round(avg_Freq - dev_Freq)||'-'||round(avg_Freq + dev_Freq)
       when frequency between (avg_Freq + 2*dev_Freq) and (avg_Freq - 2*dev_Freq) then  round(avg_Freq - 2*dev_Freq)||'-'||round(avg_Freq + 2*dev_Freq)
       when frequency between (avg_Freq + 3*dev_Freq) and (avg_Freq - 3*dev_Freq) then  round(avg_Freq - 3*dev_Freq)||'-'||round(avg_Freq + 3*dev_Freq)
          else null
           end as deviation 
FROM schema.table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT avg(frequency) AS avg_Freq
            ,stddev(frequency) AS dev_Freq
      FROM schema.table
      )sub
```

Alternatively you can add `OVER()` to each of your aggregates in your existing query:

```
select case when frequency between (avg(frequency) OVER() + stddev(frequency) OVER()) and (avg(frequency) OVER() - stddev(frequency) OVER()) then  round(avg(frequency) OVER() - stddev(frequency) OVER())||'-'||round(avg(frequency) OVER() + stddev(frequency) OVER())
       when frequency between (avg(frequency) OVER() + 2*stddev(frequency) OVER()) and (avg(frequency) OVER() - 2*stddev(frequency) OVER()) then  round(avg(frequency) OVER() - 2*stddev(frequency) OVER())||'-'||round(avg(frequency) OVER() + 2*stddev(frequency) OVER())
       when frequency between (avg(frequency) OVER() + 3*stddev(frequency) OVER()) and (avg(frequency) OVER() - 3*stddev(frequency) OVER()) then  round(avg(frequency) OVER() - 3*stddev(frequency) OVER())||'-'||round(avg(frequency) OVER() + 3*stddev(frequency) OVER())
          else null
           end as deviation 
from schema.table
```

Not 100% on redshift syntax, but believe both should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could break it into pieces by:

```
WITH
SELECT avg(frequency) as AVG, stddev(frequency) as STDDEV 
  from schema.table AS TEMP
,
SELECT case when frequency between TEMP.AVG and TEMP.STDDEV etc.
```

You will have to check the exact statements. I did it by head.